# Entity Framework: How to set model as Serializable in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
[Serializable]
public partial class user
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Creation { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public int UserTypeId { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see in my code,  my class setted as serializable. But after I update my .edmx file, this setting deleted. How can I keep Serializable after update edmx file?

Comment: I would suggest you read up on the Domain Model pattern plus how AutoMapper helps make it easier. It avoids this sort of thing and makes it easier to separate the layers of your application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you can see your class is partial so you can add another class(file) to your project and use Serializable attribute there.

```
[Serializable]
public partial class user
{

}
```

Put this in another class with the same namespace and also see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488(v=vs.90).aspx for further info about partials.