# Serialization of EF (db first) to viewstate

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, entity-framework-6

I am having some issues with trying to store EF objects into viewstate and after lots of googling (usually ending up on SO) end up with more issues.

1. I have a DB First EF 6 entity model, with auto-generated classes, one of which is called `MyRole`
2. I then have a DAL wrapping the access to the EF objects.. Here's an extract of the important parts

   ```
   namespace MyApp
   {
       public class EFDataAccess : IDisposable
       {
           private MyEntities context;

           public static IEnumerable<MyRole> GetRoles()
           {
               IEnumerable<MyRole> oRet = null;
               using (EFDataAccess oRepo = new EFDataAccess())
               {
                   oRet = oRepo.context.Roles.AsEnumerable();
               }
               return oRet;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. My ASP.Net page has the following

   ```
   ViewState["lstRoles"] = EFDataAccess.GetRoles().ToList();
   ```

   Now, the problem here is that ASP.Net barfs saying it cant add to view state as `MyRole` is not serializable.
4. So, as per [Entity Framework: How to set model as Serializable in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18693262/entity-framework-how-to-set-model-as-serializable-in-entity-framework) article, I create a new class

   ```
   namespace MyApp
   {
       [Serializable]
       public partial class MyRole
       {
       }
   }
   ```
5. All good up to now except when I now run the application, I get the following `runtime compilation error`

   ```
   Compilation Error 

   Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

   Compiler Error Message: CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyApp.MyRole> [c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyApp.MyRole> [c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)


   Source Error:

   Line xxxx: using (EFDataAccess oRepo = new EFDataAccess())
   Line xxxx: {
   Line xxxx:     oRet = oRepo.context.CallTrackerRoles.AsEnumerable();  *** THIS LINE HIGHLIGHTED RED
   Line xxxx: }
   Line xxxx: return oRet;
   ```
6. And now, this is where I am stuck. As it is saying that it is failing on an implicit conversion of the same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined a new class, probably in a different namespace or a different assembly. That class is `partial` with one part.

Comment: EF db first generated classes are marked as `partial` so you can extend them. Both classes are same namespace

Comment: But in a different assembly. `partial` is purely a C# concept. It does not exist in meta-data. You can't extend classes of different projects.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. All the EF code is within the Web App project so would assume (bad idea) that it would get compiled. What I will now do is separate out the EF data layer into a separate assembly and reference. I'll check back later on that

Comment: Smashing stuff.. I think I now (loose) understand the problem which is that because ASP.Net was compiling at runtime and creating separate assemblies. Separating into a specific assembly meant everything was "concrete".